# can't bind ngmodel in angular 9

Tags: angular, ngmodel

This is html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />

<button (click)="addtext()">add</button>
```

this is ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-post",
  templateUrl: "./post.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post.component.css"],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  name: string = "";
  addtext() {
    console.log("your name is: ", name);
  }
}
```

please help me binding this thing,something wrong

i want to write in log the text for name
and bind ngmodel as text ,name

Comment: add this with the name. `console.log("your name is: ",this.name)`

Comment: made it,it works,

Answer (score 1):

Name is a member variable of the PostComponent class. To access the name instance variable within any instance methods (in this case addtext), you need to reference it using the `this` keyword. Otherwise, it tries to access a local variable called name inside the scope of the addtext function and since there is no variable called name in that scope, it will print `undefined`. Hope this helps.

```
addtext()
{
    console.log("your name is: " + this.name);
}
```